# How to create custom find method?

Tags: javascript, find, prototype

I'm trying to create custom find method using `Array.prototype`, I tried a lot of way but i just couldn't break the loop for the first match:

```js
let arr = ["Bill", "Russel", "John", "Tom", "Eduard", "Alien", "Till"];
Array.prototype.myFind = function (callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    callback(this[i], i, this);
  }
};
arr.myFind((element, index, array) => {
  if (element[0] === "T") {
    console.log(`This is ${element} in index of ${index} in array ${array}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well right now you just have a for loop, if you want to find any element that satisfies a condition, you have to return a boolean from your callback and return the element, for which that returned boolean is `true`. If you want the index of the element you found and the initial array to be returned as well, you can return an object and destructure it:

```js
let arr = ["Bill", "Russel", "John", "Tom", "Eduard", "Alien", "Till"];
Array.prototype.myFind = function (callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if ( true == callback(this[i], i, this)) {
      return {element:this[i],index:i,array:this};
    }
  }
};
let {element,index,array} = arr.myFind((element) => element[0] === "T");

console.log(`This is ${element} in index of ${index} in array ${array}`);
```